# Spring Boot - 2.6.x application with Azure-data-table is not able to register with Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, azure-table-storage

I am trying to connect Azure table storage using Spring 2.6.4 and below dependencies are added.

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2021.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-data-tables</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But with this configuration, the service is not showing up in Eureka and getting the below error.Without azure-data-table dependency, the service is registered with Eureka.Please help.

ERROR 10236 AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0 com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ConfigClusterResolver **Cannot resolve to any endpoints from provided configuration: {defaultZone=[]}**

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: **There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty**
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:108) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:893) [eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1457) [eureka-client-1.10.17.jar!/:1.10.17]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]

Answer (score 0):

The eureka example requires 3 participants:

•   a centralized eureka server for registration and discovery

•   an example service to register with eureka that exposes a REST endpoint

•   an example client that discovers the example service via discovery, and then queries the example service on its registered REST endpoint.

**Setting up the Eureka server**

1. Edit eureka-server.properties and uncomment the two settings that makes the demo server start up faster (via disabling safeguards)
2. Build the application.
3. The above build also sets up all the libraries needed for running the demo service and the demo client.
4. Copy the WAR artifact to your tomcat deployment directory under _$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/

   ```
   cp ./eureka-server/build/libs/eureka-server-XXX-SNAPSHOT.war $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/eureka.war
   ```
5. Create (or add to) a setenv.sh in tomcat/bin/ with the following java opts (these are for the demo server to start up fast, see EurekaServerConfig.java for their documentation):

   ```
   JAVA_OPTS=" \
    -Deureka.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0 \
    -Deureka.numberRegistrySyncRetries=0"
   ```
6. Start your tomcat server. Access `http://localhost:8080/eureka` to verify the information there. Your server's eureka client should register itself in 30 seconds and you should see that information there.